# Wireless router crashes when connecting from Ubuntu only

Tags: wireless, wireless-access-point, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I bought an Acer M3-481. I am running 12.04 64 Bit with an Atheros Wifi Module. My WLAN router to which I'm trying to connect to is a Thomson TWG850 device. It seems that this device crashes every time I connect to it using this PC only.

At the beginning I thought my own wireless module on the notebook would crash. After looking at my mobile phone (android) I realised that the router kicks out all devices conntected to it. So after I shut down Ubuntu I tried with my W7 PC and everything works fine.

Furthermore, each time that happens, Ubuntu asks me for my WLAN Key (WPA). Ubuntu send out a system report for an internal error stating that the "WPA Supplicant hast crashed". I am not sure if this has anything to do with the WPA I am talking about.

Other Forums suggest deactivating N-Modus on Ubuntu or on the Router. This unfortunately doesnt help me. I have been looking in many forums, but theres no real help. A lot of people seem to face the same problem.

I am sorry, very new to ubuntu so if you need anymore info about the system, please tell me how to pull those. Sorry.

Comment: What WLAN router/AP are you using? It appears to be very broken. If one can crash this access point by simply connecting to it, this is a security issue of this device.

Comment: its a thomson twg850.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue now.

I first installed the WICD Network Manager and uninstalled the Network Manager delivered with Ubuntu. After setting up the connection I haven't had any errors since then (1 Week).